# Quitar ceros Mysql

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, mysqli

me podrían indicar por favor como quitar en MySQL los ceros a la derecha que agregar el motor de base de datos a un cambo decimal.

Como se visualiza : 5400.0000
Como debe quedar : 5400

Desde ya gracias cualquier ayuda.

Comment: Hola. Ayudaría que edites la pregunta para que sea más clara.

Comment: Hola, Bienvenido@. Las publicaciones que no contienen una descripción de un problema y donde se ubica este en especifico, no son bien recibidas por la comunidad. Por favor, revisa [como hacer un pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y edita tu pregunta para que podamos ayudarte. Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hay varias formas.

**1) EN LA BASE DE DATOS COMO UN TIPO DE DATO**

Se puede declarar de la siguiente manera

DECIMAL(3, 2) // Lo que le estamos indicando a MySQL declarando la columna de esa forma es que  soporte 3 dígitos en total, y que de esos 3 tome 2 para decimales por lo que el numero mayor que soportara es 9.99

```
Tipo de dato    Ejemplo             Numero Maximo
DECIMAL(5, 2)   500.00              999.99
DECIMAL(7,3)    1500.650            9999.999
DECIMAL(9,2)    1500000.90          9999999.99
DECIMAL(5,4)    1.0075              9.9999
DECIMAL(4,0)    5400                9999  // Quizas te refieras a este
```

**2) FORMATEANDO EL VALOR AL RECIBIRLO EN UNA CONSULTA**

- SELECT TRUNCATE(1.234,1) retornará -> 1.2 TRUNCATE(A, B) Devuelve
  el número A, manteniendo B decimales y quitando los demas a la
  derecha. Si B es 0, el resultado no tiene punto decimal.
- SELECT FORMAT(1.999, 2) retornará -> 2 es similar a Truncate pero
  redondea el número

Comment: Excelente, gracias por tu respuesta Wilfredo, obtuve exactamente lo que necesita con el truncate.

Comment: Me alegra que te haya funcionado. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

La función **FORMAT** puede ser lo que buscas:

```
SELECT FORMAT(5400.0000, 0);
```

Saludos.